# Android v 5.0+ webview HTML5, CSS3 and ES6 compatibility

Tags: android, html, css, webview, ecmascript-6

I have a hybrid Android app which uses Crosswalk.  I made the switch to Crosswalk a few months ago and it was a huge productivity boost.  I spent a great deal more time testing out on different Android OS versions and ran into far fewer issues with incomplete HTML5/CSS3/ES6 implementation - if I understand correctly because Crosswalk is based on Chromium which is not the case with earlier versions of Android.

However, the Crosswalk project has now been abandoned.  My understanding is that the post v 5.0 impleentation of the native Webview in Android is so good as to make Crosswalk obsolete.

I am now toying with dropping Crosswalk too - based on the observation that in my target market (Western Europe) Android v 5.0- market share is in single digits and falling fast.

Before I make the plunge I thought I should ask here.  Does Android v 5.0+ WebView offer a truly flat, Chrome grade, API for HTML5, ES6 and CSS3 or am I still likely to run into issues with unimplented capabilities rendered worse by "tweaks" to the OS done by the various device vendors?

To mention a few specific issues

- Can I expect a full set of CSS3 pseudo selectors to be supported
- Can I assume that I can safely work without using `-webkit` style vendor prefixes
- Will I be able to write JS code that uses `Object.keys` and other more recent comers to the JS stable

I have been unable to find a comprehensive discussion of the full set of Webview capabilities by version.  I would much appreciate any feedback on this.

---

Since I posted this question I have experimented with dropping Crosswalk and tested the results on my Moto E3Power phone which runs Android 6.  To all intents and purposes the app still works just as expected.  However, that is far from being a rigorous test.  I am putting a bounty on this question in the hope that it will yield some definitive answers.

---

Having now tested my non Crosswalk build on two devices I have run into one immediate issue.  One of the things I do is modify `cssText`.  e.g.

```
document.getElementById('id').style.cssText = 
";transform:rotate(45deg) translate(calc(1024px - 1.35em)) rotate(-45deg);"
```

which on my Android 6.0 Moto works perfectly and delivers the expected result:

- Element `#id`rotates 45 degrees
- slides out along its, rotated, X axis
- and finally rotates back -45 degrees

Surprisingly enough on an HTC Hero running Android 7.0 this does not work.  Although it makes no sense I even tried it out after adding the `-webkit-`prefix.  On both devices I upgraded Webview to the latest available version on Play Store.

Comment: Check out caniuse.com

Comment: Android 5+ WebView is based on Chromium and updated through the Play Store. You can check the version of the `Android System WebView` package installed on your own device and see its version corresponds to recently released chromium. /// Since you do not bundle it within your app (like Crosswalk) different devices have different versions and you may run into compatibility issues in your HTML app. /// You can always check the installed version at runtime and prompt the user to update their WebView implementation.

Comment: For completeness: Android WebView is not based on Chrome at all until KitKat. KitKat WebView is based on Chrome 33 and cannot be updated. See here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}       
else {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Android 19 has Chromium engine for WebView. I guess it works better with hardware acceleration.
Hardware Acceleration also do's the trick.You can use it in different levels in your application.

Application level

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Activity level

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity ... />
    <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

Comment: I haven't in fact got the authoritative answer I was waiting for.  However, I was starting to suspect myself that the missing animations on some phones was a hardware acceleration issue so by far you have provided the most useful answer which I have decided to accept

Comment: I also suffer from the same condition as yours on native apps. I tried a lot of measures and finally the measure was the best I know. WebView on android loses iOs very much both in terms of features and speed. I have not found anyone that can customize better in android. If you know please introduce for me! Thanks for bounty.

Answer (score 2):

Webview now it's not integrated with the OS but it's an independent app that can be updated from the play store, and yes it support css3 and all, 
it is not chrome, but shares the same code for rendering with chrome

> No, Chrome for Android is separate from WebView. They're both based on the same code, including a common JavaScript engine and rendering engine.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

If you say most of your user devices are +5 you should be fine.

1. WebGL
2. WebRTC
3. WebAudio
4. Form validation

Here are the features available for webview
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#does_the_new_webview_have_feature_parity_with_chrome_for_android_

Also for android > 7.0 Chrome itself it's the webview.

Comment: I do not feel that your answer adequately my question. The links you mention above are well known and talk in very generic terms about the web technologies supported by +5 webview.  I mention some very specific points such as support for CSS3 pseudo selectors, ES6 featurres etc.  I have run into some very odd issues since I ditched Crosswalk which I now mention in my question.